# Using Google Cloud Load Balancer & SSL For MANY Domains

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, lets-encrypt

I'm planning to set up HTTP/HTTPS load balancing (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) on the Google Cloud Platform for over 1,700 domains (different websites); and all will have TLS/SSL. However, you can only add up to 10 SSL certificates per load balancer, according to this: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates

How should I go about trying to set up load balancing to serve websites using Compute Engine? I'd like to have instances in several different regions, and all of the steps in adding a domain should be automated (I have the deployment process figured out).

Of course I'll be providing my own SSL certificates. I can add up to 100 domains per certificate using Let's Encrypt (https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/). But do I need a separate certificate for each domain for the Google Cloud load balancer? But if I can use one certificate for every 100 domains, does that mean I can only use a load balancer for up to 1,000 domains (10*100)? Would I have to create multiple load balancers, each with its own Frontend, using the same Backend service? How many load balancers am I allowed to create per project?

Answer (score 4):

We also had the same scenario and requirement (1000+ domains, letsencrypt SSL and Google LoadBalancer) but alas couldn't use Google Load Balancer to do that. Instead we made an TCP LoadBalancer instead of an HTTPS one, so that we could handle the 443 port.

Now the request directly came to our instances (even with ssl), and we made conf for all the domains in nginx and all the domains had their ssl certifciates configured using letsencrypt and serve the app based on the domain.

Comment: GCP can do this but managing certs with lets encrypt is not full auto with load balancers (though it can be script with gcloud). You are also losing out on pushing TLS termination to the edge, offloading the weight of encryption on the GCP and optional CDN/security shield with that approach.

Comment: so this way all your compute engine instances have ssl provisioned for all the domains you support ? if thats the case then isn't it exhausting. think of a case when you have more than millions of domains? well i might be wrong. but i ll be thankful if you tell me to create a bulk shared host like firebase with GCP.  please reply waiting ...

Answer (score 3):

The limitation on number of certs is by IP, not by load balancer. The number of certs by ip is now 15 on each per the [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates). If in your case the sites can use a shared cert, then that would cover 1500 domains per IP address.

[GCP quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) have a default but you can request an increase if your case needs it.